# Matplotlib: plot multiple columns into a figure with different y axes

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I want to plot a figure similar with this(sorry it does not look very good):

[image]

with data, let say, like this:

```
y = np.random.rand(10,3)
y[:,0]= np.arange(1,11)
df = pd.DataFrame(y, columns=["X", "Volume", "Time"])
df

X   Volume  Time
0   1.0 0.517895    0.182525
1   2.0 0.488399    0.252989
2   3.0 0.992292    0.941301
3   4.0 0.147368    0.650542
4   5.0 0.236345    0.662650
5   6.0 0.913300    0.539643
6   7.0 0.373740    0.379043
7   8.0 0.752482    0.875370
8   9.0 0.040096    0.097381
9   10.0    0.793734    0.625026
```

Does anyone know how to do it? thanks, I try to dig in stack overflow but not found any similar question.
Thanks ahead for any idea and suggestion!!

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y = np.random.rand(10,3)
y[:,0]= np.arange(1,11)
df = pd.DataFrame(y, columns=['x', 'v', 't'])

fig = plt.figure() # Create matplotlib figure

ax = fig.add_subplot(111) # Create matplotlib axes
ax2 = ax.twinx() # Create another axes that shares the same x-axis as ax.

width = 0.4

df.plot(x='x',y='v',kind='bar', color='red', ax=ax, width=width, position=1)
df.t.plot(x='x', y='t[::-1]',kind='bar', color='blue', ax=ax2, width=width, position=0)

ax.set_ylabel('v')
ax2.set_ylabel('t')


plt.show()
```

Comment: hi @Tanvir yes you plotting is also great. But I am looking for put the 2 column, one on the bottom and the other one on the top. I found the solution actually,  after use "ax2=ax.twinx()", flip the range of ax2 y axis by "ax2.set_ylim(BIG_NUMBER, SMALL_NUMBER)". Still thank you !

Comment: yeah twinx work for same x axis but different y axis. it is nice to know that your problem have solved.

Answer (score 0):

here is my solution. It is pretty simple actually, after use ax2=ax.twinx(), flip the range of ax2 y axis by ax2.set_ylim(BIG_NUMBER, SMALL_NUMBER)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y = np.random.rand(10,3)
y[:,0]= np.arange(1,11)
df = pd.DataFrame(y, columns=['x', 'v', 't'])
df['x'] = np.arange(1, 11, 1)

fig = plt.figure() # Create matplotlib figure

ax = fig.add_subplot(111) # Create matplotlib axes
ax2 = ax.twinx() # Create another axes that shares the same x-axis as ax.


ax.bar(df['x'],df['v'], color='red', alpha=0.8)
ax.set_ylabel('v', color='red')
ax.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor='red')
ax.set_ylim(0, 1.5)

ax2.bar(df['x'], df['t'], color='blue', alpha=0.5)
ax2.set_ylabel('t', color='b')
ax2.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor='blue')
ax2.set_ylim(1.5, 0)

plt.show()
```